# Standard JavaScript for this

Tags: javascript, web, client-side

I'm working on some 15 year old code and there is a line that only seems to actually get set and be usuable in IE. I can't change that line because there actually more of them and referenced in other asp pages, I know, a nightmare.
The code:

```
parent.frmParent.id_item.value = '<%=Request("id_item")%>' //The actual string
                                                           //doesn't matter...
```

I've tried:

```
var parent.document.getElementById("id_item").Value
var parent.document.getElementById("frmParent")("id_item").Value
```

Am I close? It must exist in the DOM.

Comment: Are you sure that the `<%=Request("id_item")%>` bit doesn't have to do with a server-side templating framework instead?

Comment: Yes, it's asp server-side, which should make it irrelevant. It does get a value in some browsers but FF isn't one of them. The main issue is that I can of course just use the value of the server-side code throughout the partial page but it gets manipulated through out page using JavaScript residing on parent pages. So without re-writing the site(it's going away) I just need a hack to get it working with FF

Comment: It seems like what should be working isn't. I can confirm the server side is returning a value and the parent.document.getElementById("id_item").value is correct as I knew but isn't working so it wouldn't suprise that in the maze of other 1997 JavaScript wire are getting crossed. Thanks for the help trying everyone I'm just going to give up on this for now.

Comment: In the web console of FF I did see that :
[09:30:08.744] parent.frmParent is undefined

Answer (score 1):

It should be the lower case `value` (instead of `Value`)...

```
parent.document.getElementById("id_item").value
```

Comment: Ah, fair point @Alnitak... code blindness, and typing too fast

Answer (score 0):

> Am I close? It must exist in the DOM.

I suspect you're looking for `.value` - i.e. just in lower case, e.g.

```
var val = parent.document.getElementById("id_item").value;
```

which would be the way to retrieve the value from an element with id `id_item`.

However I suspect that's not what the code is supposed to be doing...

Comment: Yes, I am trying to retrieve the value. I made typos and v's are lowercase, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go on a long shot here:

`<%=Request("id_item")%>` could be referring to the querystring value for the key `id_item` of the .NET Request object. try using this instead:

```
var qs = window.location.search(1);
var items = qs.split('&');
var pair;
var result;

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    pair = items[i].split('=');

    if (pair[0] === 'id_item') { // the QS key
        result = pair[1]; // the QS value
        break;
    }
}

var element = document.getElementById(result);
```

It might be worth putting the querystring logic into a function e.g. `getQuerystringValue(querystring, key)`.

On a side note, the property is `.value`, not `.Value`, javascript is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is tagged `javascript`, but this snippet is definitely server-side: `<%=Request("id_item")%>`.

This will simply print out the `id_item` field from the `Request` collection (or possibly call a method named `Request`). You should look into what server-side frameworks are running behind this page and update your post accordingly. Without more knowledge of what language you're using, I can't help more.

Comment: Oh it's holding a value and in some browsers the JavaScript has the value FF is not one of them which is the goal here.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I see it now. Your problem here probably is that IE will automatically add things that are ids in the document as properties of the corresponding window object. In those cases you will want to replace the property access with a `document.getElementById(idName)`.

By looking at your example, my psychic powers say that `frmParent` is a normal Javascript property (pointing to another javascript window) band `id_item` is an element ID (of something in the grandparent document). If this is the case, see if the following works:

```
parent.frmParent.document.getElementById("id_item").value = /*...*/
```